# Allowing fields to be nulled in MongoDB schemas

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I currently have an DB that has optional parameter fields in the schema JSON objects. At the moment, when the fields are UPDATED from an existing value(whether that be string, date, or otherwise) to null, upon retrieving the object the field is not actually nulled. How do I modify these schema fields to allow certain fields (say, the last three) in the object to be nulled upon an update, and displayed as such upon a subsequent GET request? I've tried making the `type` an array and adding null, but that clearly is not correct. Ive also tried `default: null` but that also did not work.

```
data: {
    // Mandatory params
    name:    { type: String, required: true, index: true }, 
    id:      { type: String, required: true },              
    type:    { type: String, required: true },              

    // Optional params
    parent:        { type: db.objectId(), ref: 'organisation' }
    parentSpid:    { type: String }, 
    memberStatus:  { type: String },
    memberTier:    { type: String },
    memberExpiry:  { type: Date }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Mongoose to wrap mongo? Under the hood, your queries will be using the `$set` operator which explicitly does not overwrite fields without a new value.

You should use the `$unset` operator to `nullify` fields.

For example, if you wished to `nullify` parent you would do:

`Model.findOneAndUpdate({ ...QUERY }, { $unset: { parent: 1 } });`

The $unset object can contain any fields you wish to nullify. Be wary that validators don't always run on updates in Mongoose. See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: So I've gotten  it to accept null as a value, halfway there. It no longer just returns the previous value once updated. But now upon a GET for that object, it is trimming those fields from the response. Instead of having them trimmed, I would want the field to be returned with a value of "null"

Comment: Are you making MongoDb queries? Or mongoose queries? If Mongoose, are you performing a `lean` query?

Comment: Mongoose, no `lean`

Comment: In that case the query response should contain the `NULL` fields. However, if you are referring to the payload returned by a GET request, the `NULL` fields will be stripped because `toObject` method which will be called by the body parser removes them. To avoid this you will need to coerce the Mongoose object returned by the query into an object yourself, including these `NULL` fields.

Comment: Actually I am not quite correct. Only `undefined` fields will be removed in that way. `NULL` fields should remain present after both a `toObject` & `toJSON` methods, as well as `JSON.stringify`. It would be good to get some more detail on the query you are performing & at what stage you are seeing that the `NULL` field is missing?